# Export Database & Zip it using PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, shell-exec

I create a quick route that triggering an fn that runs `shell_exec()` to back up my database.

```
mysqldump -u john -p123 db1 > /home/john/db1.04-20-21-11-28-am.sql
```

To save server space, I also want to *zip* what I **dumped**

```
tar -czvf db1.04-20-21-11-28-am.sql.tar.gz db1.04-20-21-11-28-am.sql && rm -rf db1.04-20-21-11-28-am.sql
```

I'm not sure why the zip command never runs even if I put a `sleep()` after the first one, and in betweens.

**What did I do wrong?**

> ***Note** : the tar command working perfectly if I copy and run it on the command line in the server.*

---

## Code

```
public function dbBackUp()
{

    $un = env('DB_USERNAME');
    $pw = env('DB_PASSWORD');
    $db = env('DB_DATABASE');

    $date = date('m-d-y-g-i-a');

    $cmd = 'mysqldump -u ' . $un . ' -p' . $pw . ' ' . $db . ' > /home/john/' . $db . '.'.$date.'.sql';
    $result = shell_exec($cmd);

    sleep(2);

    $cmd2 = 'tar -czvf '. $db . '.'. $date .'.sql.tar.gz '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql && rm -rf '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql';
    $result2 = shell_exec($cmd2);
    
    $un = env('DB_USERNAME');
    $pw = env('DB_PASSWORD');
    $db = env('DB_DATABASE_BABIES');
    $cmd3 = 'mysqldump -u ' . $un . ' -p' . $pw . ' ' . $db . ' > /home/john/' . $db . '.'.$date.'.sql';
    $result3 = shell_exec($cmd3);

    sleep(2);

    $cmd4 = 'tar -czvf '. $db . '.'. $date .'.sql.tar.gz '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql && rm -rf '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql';
    $result4 = shell_exec($cmd4);
    sleep(2);

    $data = []; 

    if($result != null ){
        return View::make('layouts.dbBackUp');
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: adding sleep, running the actual command on the actual server just in case command is not clean or have typo, check the server if the files are generated as expected and it's not.

Comment: @NicoHaase I usually tried to debug as much as I know before I started asking, did you see my post, before asking that ?

Comment: Sorry, I could not guess that. So, what do all these `$result` variables contain? As far as I see, you don't return any errors for them (`2>&1` is missing)

Comment: They all return `null` and also, look like `Tim` pointed out what I missed.

Comment: I would assume that by adding `2>&1` to the end of each command, you would have received an error message

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank-you, let me try that.

Comment: @NicoHaase : Do you know ? It store in a really long path now. When I extract the zip, I see /home/john/db1.04-20-21-11-28-am.sql ... I have to go into 3 layers to see my .sql, is there way to place it on theh root of the zip folder ?

Comment: @NicoHaase I added on all my commands now `shell_exec($cmd2.' 2>&1');` but result still the same, am I suppose to see some kinf of errors when there're errors ?

Comment: It depends on what you do with all these `$result` variables. You never echo them or use hem in any other way - have you tried dumping them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing "/home/john/" part from the tar command so it wont find the file.

Maybe this will help:

```php
//change to the directory that contains the file you want to zip
chdir('/home/john/');

$cmd2 = 'tar -czvf '. $db . '.'. $date .'.sql.tar.gz '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql && rm -rf '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql';
$result2 = shell_exec($cmd2);
```

Comment: You're right, it's working now. Thanks. It store in a really long path now. When I extract the zip, I see `/home/john/db1.04-20-21-11-28-am.sql` ... I have to go into 3 layers to see my .sql, is there way to place it on theh root of the zip folder ?

Comment: You could try chdir first then run it "locally" from there.. so something like:
chdir('/home/john/');
$cmd2 = 'tar -czvf '. $db . '.'. $date .'.sql.tar.gz '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql && rm -rf '. $db .'.'.$date.'.sql';
$result2 = shell_exec($cmd2);